# Add a full cookbook to a role in Chef web gui

Tags: user-interface, chef-infra, role, cookbook

When creating or editing a Role in the GUI I can't find a way to add a cookbook.
I have my recipes grouped in different cookbooks, but it seems when I create a role I have to add every recipe one by one. It does not make sense to me.
For instance, I have a cookbook that adds about 30 configuration files, each one with its own recipe. I would like to add that cookbook to a role, I don't know how.
It seems when I create a role I can add sub-roles and recipes, but not cookbooks. To me is like somebody asks me for my recipes for soups, and instead of giving him my book with soup recipes I start searching around for all my recipes about soup.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

That's the way chef works. You set a run list of recipes.

If you wish to do all in one pass create a recipe named `all_recipes`for exemple and containing

```
include_recipe "you_cookbook::recipe_name1"
include_recipe "you_cookbook::recipe_name2"
include_recipe "you_cookbook::recipe_name3"
```

But if you intent is to manage 30 files in the same way, you may loop over them in a single recipe instead of doing one recipe per file.

Having multiple recipes in a cookbook is more to manage different cases (service or cronjob, unix system or windows system, etc).

All in all it sounds like a bad design at first. (No judgement, just a feeling with the few information you gave)

---

For your soup exemple, you're taking it the wrong way. 
It's not that someone ask you for recipes, it's you telling a chef to cook things.

If you want him to cook everything in a cokbook, you have to tell him that's what you want, but a recipe for a particular soup may reference other 'common' recipes (like peel potatoes) etc.

Comment: I'd also mention that if you put `recipe[cookbookname]` in your runlist, that's not adding the 'cookbook' to your runlist.  That's just shorthand for `recipe[cookbookname::default]` ie, a single recipe.

Comment: @TejayCardon Thanks, I had a doubt about talking about it and didn't find how to phrase it. Given OP is using GUI (manage I think) and can't add the whole cookbook in his/her point of view I've assumed there's no `default.rb` in his/her cookbook.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right.  Just trying to figure out where the idea of adding a cookbook to a runlist came from.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody. I had the impression that I should be able to add a full cookbook to a role. So I misunderstood the purpose of a cookbook (I am just starting with Chef). What I did was a mix of your solutions, I added a cookbookname::default, which includes all the recipes in that cookbook.